# Python - Optional Command Line Argument

Tags: python, list, command, arguments, line

I would like to have an option -n, that will allow users to specify a size of a list. The default will be 30. So:

```
./findNumberOfPlayers.py -n10
```

I haven't done any command line arguments with python before but am confused with how to include `-n10` within the program. I understand I would `import sys` and have 12 assigned to `sys.argv[1]` but how does it work with `-n10`?

Thank You! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n", "--number", help="Enter a number", type=int)
```

You can then access the arg like this -

```
args = parser.parse_args()
num_players = args.number if args.number else 30
```